# Asp.Net Core Cascading Select Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

There are innumerable examples of doing this aged question on the www.  But nothing has gotten me over the finish line.  Here is target method on the StudentController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<CampusOrganization> GetOrgsByCampusId(int id)
    {
        var results = repository.GetOrgsByCampusId(id);
        return results;
    }
```

This an example of what it returns:

```
[
{
    "campusId": 441,
    "requireAssociate": true,
    "appointments": null,
    "organizationId": 362,
    "longName": "Alpha Chi Omega"
},
{
    "campusId": 441,
    "requireAssociate": true,
    "appointments": null,
    "organizationId": 363,
    "longName": "Alpha Gamma Delta"
}, ...
```

The second select (from top) is dependent on the first:

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SelectedCampus.OrganizationId">Campus:</label>
            <select asp-for="SelectedCampus.OrganizationId" asp-items="@Model.Campuses"  class="form-control" id="Campus">
                <option>Select one</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="SelectedCampus.OrganizationId" class="text-danger"></span>

            <label asp-for="Student.OrganizationId">Organization:</label>
            <select asp-for="Student.OrganizationId" asp-items="@Model.CampusOrganizations" class="form-control" id="Org">
                <option>Select one</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Student.OrganizationId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Here is the Ajax request which is completing without error:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Campus").on("change", function () {
    $list = $("#Org");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Student/GetOrgsByCampusId",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: $("#Campus").val() }, //id of the campus which is used to extract organzitions
        traditional: true,
        success: function (result) {
            $list.empty();
            $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                $list.append('<option value="' + item["OrganizationId"] + '"> ' + item["LongName"] + ' </option>');
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, msg) {
            alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + '\n' + "status: " + xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);;
        }
    }); //end ajax()
}); //end onchange function
```

});

Finally, here is an image of what is going wrong. The .each loop is iterating in the Ajax code above and completing without error.  So I suspect, what I am building in the loop is not correct,

[before and after changing Campus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLq0X.jpg)

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. Use the correct case `organizationId` and `longName`

Comment: `item.organizationId` and `item.longName` (note the capitalization)

Comment: But you should not be returning all that extra data that you never even use. Just returns a model containing only the 2 properties you need

Comment: Wow.  I did not pay attention to the fact that JSON changed the capitalization from that used in the code and database.  That fixed it.